# Unable to run scripts from Nextjs | using exec from child_process

Tags: python, node.js, next.js, process, exec

I am trying to run simple py/sh scripts from nextjs using exec but i am not able to achieve it.

Kind help would be much appreciated.

Process is simple:

> I am calling server Actions in my code, which executes the script

page.tsx

```
"use client";

import { pythonExec } from "./action";

export default function PythonClicker() {
  return <div onClick={() => pythonExec()}>Hello there</div>;
}
```

server action

```
"use server";

// import { exec } from "child_process";
export const pythonExec = async () => {
  const { exec } = require("child_process");
  console.log("I am called  ");
  exec('"sample-script.py"');
};
```

sample-script.py

```
print("Hello world")
```

p.s: I am called is being logged, only the "Hello world" is not getting logged.
I also want to return values from the script and use consume it in my server action

Reproducible code: https://github.com/krishnaacharyaa/python-nextjs

Comment: IDK, maybe `sample-script.py` needs a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) as its first line? `#! /usr/bin/env python`

Answer (score 0):

For expected behavior, you need to make sure that the `exec` function is properly handling the script's output and errors. I updated you `pythonExec` function.

`pythonExec` :-

```
 "use server";

const { exec } = require("child_process");

export const pythonExec = async () => {
    console.log("I am called");

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec("python sample-script.py", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                reject(error);
                return;
            }
            if (stderr) {
                console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                reject(stderr);
                return;
            }
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            resolve(stdout);
        });
    });
};
```

Then you can do `Async/Await` in you client page to use the output from Python script. Consider following example.

`page.tsx` :-

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { pythonExec } from "./action";

export default function PythonClicker() {
  const [output, setOutput] = useState('');

  const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await pythonExec();
      setOutput(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error executing Python script:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={handleClick}>Run Python Script</div>
      {output && <p>Script Output: {output}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And then Make sure your `sample-script.py` file is in root folder like this.

[image]